# Collection helpers in React containers sometimes missing

Tags: reactjs, meteor, containers, meteor-publications

As far as I understand, collection helpers are implemented using transforms on documents. However, sometimes my helpers seem to be missing.

In foo.js I define:

```
owner() {
  const rel = FooBarRelations.findOne({
    fooId: this._id,
    isOwner: true,
  });

  if (rel) {
    return rel.barId;
  }
}
```

In my container. I subscribe to a composite publication (reywood:publish-composite) and when `sub.ready()` I fetch: `fooDoc = Foo.findOne(fooId)`.

The returned document does not have `owner` property, sometimes.
`fooDoc.owner is not a function`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that I'm using [low level publication code](http://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html#Subscription-added) and set `fooDoc.owner` manually.

This causes `fooDoc.owner` to be a string sometimes and hence the error message is thrown.